# Split column in pandas and retain the first split

Tags: python, pandas

The following will work:

```py
s = pd.Series(["one_here_there", "two_here_there", "there_there_here"])
s.str.split("_", n=1).transform(lambda x: x[0])
```

I'm wondering if there's something more "built in", that avoids the use of `lambda`, as I've heard they are often abused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do not need to use lambda here.

You can use

```
s.str.split("_", n=1).str[0]
```

Or you can use

```
s.str.split("_", n=1).str.get(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try `.str.split().str[index]`

```
s.str.split("_").str[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes we have `str`

```
s.str.split("_", n=1).str[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [itemgetter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) function.

Use it like so:

```
import operator

get_first = operator.itemgetter(0)
s = pd.Series(["one_here_there", "two_here_there", "there_there_here"])

s.str.split("_", n=1).transform(get_first)
```

Answer (score 0):

add `expand=True` and take `first` column

```
s.str.split("_",expand=True)[0]
```

ouptut:

```
Out[15]:
0      one
1      two
2    there
Name: 0, dtype: object
```